# Font size in Windows 11

Tags: windows

I have the same problem with MaryD-6001 in this [Microsoft Q&A thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/595762/ability-to-change-the-system-font-at-windows-11.html):

> "This does not change the font size for the menu bar or the Bookmark bar and that font is about a size 8 which is ridiculous. Everyone says to do this through the Accessibility settings but it doesn't work so why don't you come up with a real solution. Windows 11 is worse than 10 for making the menu bar font smaller on the browsers and on other programs purchased and installed on the Windows 11 system. I can't believe we can't adjust that. If all the comments were read many people have tried this without any success. Windows 11 is great for the near-sighted computer tech people but not for a far-sighted person corrected to 20-20 vision!!!!!!!
> I am totally sorry I upgraded to this platform!"

What shall I do?

Comment: Have you tried DIsplay , Scale factor ?  I do this and do not have anything like perfect sight. I an using Windows 11 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Scale/Zoom in the settings (Settings>System>Display>Scale) is what you're looking for:
[image]